# How to reinstall Enterprise Manager for Oracle database on 11gR2

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I installed Oracle Database 11gR2 on Windows 7 using the OUI but just before the finish screen it gave a warning stating that Enterprise Manager could not be setup and gave a list of commands to execute through the command-line.

Just as I executed one of them the antivirus installed i.e. AVG Antivirus gave a threat from file `emagent.exe`. Along with this file many other files required for Enterprise Manager to be setup were deleted by the antivirus.

Is there a way to re-install Enterprise Manager for the database already created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-install OEM with an existing database repository.  Just follow the installer screens for setting up an additional OMS node and fill in the database repository information when asked.  If the first install completed correctly everything should work, if not you can start again and just delete the repository first (instructions to do this are in the install notes).

Comment: I tried a fresh installation. Now I get the following error : SEVERE: Listener is not up or database service is not registered with it. Start
the Listener and register database service and run EM Configuration Assistant ag
ain .
Refer to the log file at E:\app\Bhavin\cfgtoollogs\emca\ocp11g\emca_2012_12_09_0
2_17_51.log for more details.
Could not complete the configuration. Refer to the log file at E:\app\Bhavin\cfg
toollogs\emca\ocp11g\emca_2012_12_09_02_17_51.log for more details.